# Has my office chair done enough wear to the carpet to damage it beyond repair?

Tags: carpet, damage

The carpet in my apartment has noticeable indentations from my office chair in it. I used a standard office chair with plastic wheels on the bottom for two years, but I didn't actually roll on the wheels hardly ever while sitting in the chair.

I'm worried that the marks left on the carpet from the chair may be permanent, and I'm worried that I may have ruined the carpet.

I've attached pictures of the carpet. Any advice you can offer helps. Thanks!

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: the pictures don't show anything specific ... try brushing the carpet fibers all in the same direction ... that may reveal the damaged area more clearly

Comment: The answer would be a matter of opinion,

Comment: it does looks like some loops have been split, which is that extra fuzzy look in the first picture. I don't know if you consider that damage though; it's more wear and tear to me. Just vacuum it up and use a chairmat before it gets any worse and pile starts shedding; then it's going to look a lot worse and would likely need replacing. I think as of this moment, it should be passible if addressed pronto.

Comment: @dandavis Write that up as an answer.

Comment: Looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: Consider having the carpet professionally cleaned then when dry use a chairmat. From the pictures it does does not appear to be damaged.

Answer (score 3):

Any & all carpet wear is 'beyond repair'.

That's a cut pile* carpet, known generically as a twist. The first time you ever set foot on it some of the twisting comes very, very slightly untwisted & the ends go 'fluffy' rather than remaining whole twisted threads.
Cut a piece of string & play with the cut end for a while… then try to re-twist it like new.
Not possible.

With an office chair you are concentrating this 'fluffy' wear & tear to a circle.

So, whilst with a carpet washer you will be able to lift the pile up again to some extent, you can never re-twist the 'fluffy' bits back into 'strings'.

*as opposed to a *loop* pile, where there are no ends to each thread, each loops back into the backing.

For future reference - it doesn't look so pretty, but either get a chair mat, or as I tend to do for our home office corners, put a new piece of identical carpet over the main carpet, as a sacrificial layer. When it looks too bad, I replace it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look too bad, hit it with a carpet shampoo machine. (either rent one or call a specialist carpet cleaner)

Carpets are a mass produced commodity that gain their uniformity as a result of the manufacturing process. There is no economical way to repair them.  All wear is permanent.